# How to bind FloatRatingView rating to variable using RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I am attempting to integrate this library with my RxSwift project, https://github.com/glenyi/FloatRatingView

I am unable to get the updated rating.
Here is how I have created the FloatRatingView in the **Controller**,

```
let starRater : FloatRatingView = {
let floatRatingView = FloatRatingView()
floatRatingView.emptyImage = UIImage(named: "EmptyStar")
return floatRatingView
}()
```

The **Model** contains the following,

```
let my_rating = Variable<Float?>(nil)
```

What I want to be able to do is to update the value in the `my_rating` variable when a user changes the rating by tapping on a star. Here is what I've written for this,

```
_ = starRater.rx.rating
   .asObservable()
   .bindTo(viewModel.my_rating.rx_value)
```

But here is the error I'm receiving.

> Value of type 'Reactive FloatRatingView' has no member 'rating'

Here is how I will retrieve the value from `my_rating` variable,

```
let stars = self.my_rating.value
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bindable sink for the property, it would be something like this:

```
extension Reactive where Base: FloatRatingView {

    /// Bindable sink for `rating` property
    public var progress: UIBindingObserver<Base, Float> {
        return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: self.base) { floatRatingView, rating in
            floatRatingView.rating = rating
        }
    }

}
```